# CAPSPageMenu Autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I'm trying to implement a CAPSPageMenu. Unfortunately I have a few problems with the Layout of my views.

```
    // MARK: - Scroll menu setup

    // Initialize view controllers to display and place in array
    var controllerArray : [UIViewController] = []

    let controller1 : EventsFeedViewController = EventsFeedViewController(nibName: "ViewControllerOne", bundle: nil)
    controller1.title = "Test1"
    controllerArray.append(controller1)

    let controller2 : LocationsFeedViewController = LocationsFeedViewController(nibName: "ViewControllerTwo", bundle: nil)
    controller2.title = "Test2"
    controllerArray.append(controller2)

    // Customize menu (Optional)
    let parameters: [CAPSPageMenuOption] = [
        .MenuItemSeparatorWidth(0.0),
        .UseMenuLikeSegmentedControl(true),
        .MenuItemSeparatorPercentageHeight(0.0),
        .SelectedMenuItemLabelColor(UIColor(red: 18.0/255.0, green: 150.0/255.0, blue: 225.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)),
        .ScrollMenuBackgroundColor(UIColor.whiteColor()),
        .SelectionIndicatorColor(UIColor(red: 18.0/255.0, green: 150.0/255.0, blue: 225.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0))
    ]


    // Initialize page menu with controller array, frame, and optional parameters
    pageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, self.view.frame.width, self.view.frame.height), pageMenuOptions: parameters)


    // Lastly add page menu as subview of base view controller view
    // or use pageMenu controller in you view hierachy as desired

    // Optional delegate
    pageMenu!.delegate = self

    // self.view.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)
    self.addChildViewController(pageMenu!)
    self.view.addSubview(pageMenu!.view)
    pageMenu!.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Have anyone a idea what i do wrong?

[image: Screenshot]

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working fine with two view controllers :

```
import UIKit
import PageMenu

class ViewController: UIViewController, CAPSPageMenuDelegate {

    var aPageMenu : CAPSPageMenu?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var controllerArray : [UIViewController] = []

        let profileVC =  self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VC1")
        profileVC.title = "VC 1"
        controllerArray.append(profileVC)

        let scheduleVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VC2")
        scheduleVC.title = "VC 2"
        controllerArray.append(scheduleVC)

        let menuParam: [CAPSPageMenuOption] = [
            .MenuItemSeparatorWidth(1.0),
            .MenuMargin(20.0),
            .MenuHeight(40.0),
            .UseMenuLikeSegmentedControl(true),
            .MenuItemSeparatorRoundEdges(true),
            .SelectionIndicatorHeight(2.0),
            .MenuItemSeparatorPercentageHeight(0.5)
        ]

        aPageMenu = CAPSPageMenu(viewControllers: controllerArray, frame: CGRectMake(0.0, 64.0, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width, UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.height-64.0), pageMenuOptions: menuParam)
        aPageMenu!.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(aPageMenu!.view)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: hey thanks for your answer. the code is basically the same as mine. but I use .xib files and no storyboard. i think the problem is, that my VC1 and VC2 have a size of width = 600.000000 height = 600.000000. And so "self.view.frame.width" output 600 i think.  But I have no Idea why.

Comment: @Moritz Ok then just test updated code. Get screen width by `UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width`

Comment: the result looks like this. It is only 1/3 of the screen size... http://i.stack.imgur.com/LcPjS.png

Comment: Okay I got it. I have changed all 'self.view.frame.width' with 'UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size.width' in the CAPSPageMenu.swift file and Initialize the pageMenu with 'self.view.frame.width' thank you very much!

Comment: @Moritz The real problem here is, that you're initializing CAPSPageMenu object probably in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear method. At that time, autolayout haven't done its job yet, and your view's frame is bigger than screen (this might be the case only when loading the view from .xib, not sure about that now). You should initialize CAPSPageMenu object in viewDidLayoutSubviews.

Comment: We have lost with this component more time than it is worth. My advice is to write custom controller by yourself or use something else. CAPSPageMenu code is obsolete and too long to not be buggy

Comment: It would be better if you write own component or find other implementation. This one is old and ugly

Comment: @AshishKakkad Any suggestion for manage selectionIndicatorWidth ?

Comment: how can i remove the little white space just below menu item @AshishKakkad